# Solid Mechanics book recommendations

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education, solid-mechanics

I'm searching for a book on [Solid Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_mechanics) that explains the topics intuitively (similar to Kline explanations on *Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach*). Also the book should have the derivation (and motivation) of the formulas used (if it has the historical context even better). Does anyone know a book that falls into this category?

Answer (score 2):

"Theory of Elasticity" by Timoshenko and Goodier has explanations of a lot of solid mechanics of isotropic solids in the elastic regime. Also useful for the same general area is "Theory of Elasticity" by Landau and Lifshitz. If you find them rather heavy going then "Electromechanics and MEMS" by Jones and Nenadic has easier derivations of some particular parts of solid mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this one recently. It had a good chapter on stress and strain with a lot of derivation. Coming from Physics, not Engineering, it was a good primer. Lots of equations, derivations and prose.

*Polymer Engineering Science and Viscoelasticity: An Introduction*
 By Hal F. Brinson, L. Catherine Brinson

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781489974846

https://books.google.com/books?id=QWS4-ohiK-wC&pg=PA34&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I gave a look and for me this book as little motivation, it only states the formulas.